# What is the meaning of this method?

Tags: android

This is all my code:

```
public class photo extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageView iv;
Button bt;
ImageButton ib;
Intent i ;
Bitmap bmp;
final static int cameraData =0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    intsallttion();

}
private void intsallttion() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
    ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib);

    bt.setOnClickListener(this);
    ib.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.bt:

        break;

    case R.id.ib:
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i,cameraData);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
}
```

I didn't understand this method:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

What does this method do?

Comment: Have you bothered to look [here in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivityForResult)? Because you should be able to ask something a little more specific than "What does this method do?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you opened the activity of the camera by `startActivityForResult` , then as Libin said to you , you are getting the result there; the result is the picture. I tried to add some coments:

```
     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      // you check the result code that you got from the activity of the camera
      // If the user took successfully a picture you get RESULT_OK else RESULT_CANCELED
      if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
           // The picture is communicated from the activity of the camera to your activity 
           // by intent as an extras Bundle : you put this bundle in bundle
           Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
           // you take the bitmap (your picture is in format bitmap)form this extras 
           bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
           // you are showing the bitmap in the ImageView iv
           iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not understand exactly this 2 LINES

           Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
           // you take the bitmap (your picture is in format bitmap)form this extras 

           bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

Comment: You should read a little bit more about [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) which allow you to cummunicate between activities. [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) is a class that allows to manipulate pictures in android.   
نعم

Comment: to get the "data" from sent by the intent. to make it simpler 
Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

Answer (score 1):

As per your code your are invoking the Camera to capture an image. since you started the camera activity using startActivityForResult your expecting some result back from the camera activity.

When the image is captured by the came activity the startActivityForResult will  be called with  captured result (image).

Answer (score 1):

`startActivityForResult` invokes android's internal intent (in your case it is to open camera and user can take picture).

Once picture is taken, it returns control to `onActivityResult` handler, where you can check if `resultCode` is `RESULT_OK` and take necessary action, like in your example it is setting image on ImageView using `iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);`